# how to link static library to makefile in linux

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I have created a static library using database makefile **project/database/Makefile** like this

```
rm -rf libdatabase.a
database.o: database.cpp  database.h
    g++ -c -o database.o database.cpp
    ar rvs libdatabase.a database.o
if [ -f libdatabase.a ];
then
   echo "Database-Library Build Success"
   cp libdatabase.a ../LIBs/
else
    echo "databse-Library Build Failure"
fi
```

then i going to link it in main make file **project/Main/Makefile** like this

```
rm -rf testdate
INCPATH  = -I../database
LIBPATH  = -L../LIBs
testdate:main.o libdatabase.a
    g++ -o testdate libdatabase.a main.o
main.o: main.cpp database.h
    g++ -c -o main.o main.cpp
```

but its throwing error like :
make: *** No rule to make target `database.h', needed by`main.o'.  Stop.

Plese some one coluld help me out of this. i am new to linux.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra backslash in your makefile at the end of the `LIBPATH` variable assignment.  That's causing the next line (the `testdate:...` target) to be considered part of the variable value for `LIBPATH`.  That in turn means the recipe line after that (the `g++ -o testdate ...` line) has no target defined, which is why you get that error.

Remove the backslash:

```
LIBPATH  = -L../LIBs
```

Comment: Thanks for reply its working fine , I am having one more problem colud u please check it once

Comment: You should open a new SO question if you have a different problem.  This error means that you've listed the file `database.h` as a prerequisite, but make cannot find that file.  Does it exist?  Is it in some other directory?  Make cannot guess where on your filesystem it is, so if you write `database.h` make will look in the current directory and if it's not there it will fail.